# infinite loop caused by append SWi prolog

Tags: prolog, append

I am trying a code that adds a value to a list which is initially empty.
program keeps going to infinite loop or out of stack, when using append.

I am using SWI Prolog and I am new to Prolog.

```
getcardvalueList([],[_]).
getcardvalueList([H|Ts],[_]):-
   getcardvalue(H,Val),
   append([_],[Val],Vl),
   getcardvalueList(Ts,Vl).

append([X|Y],Z,[X|W]) :- append(Y,Z,W).
append([],X,X).
```

Comment: Where do you get an infinite loop? I cannot see that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using lists in a strange way, I'm unsure about the purpose of that code.

Anyway, I think you're attempting to code a [maplist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3), so this could do

```
getcardvalueList(Cards, Values) :-
   maplist(getcardvalue, Cards, Values).
```

**If** you were attempting to this, I can show the 'amended' code:

```
getcardvalueList([],[]).
getcardvalueList([Card|Cards],[Val|Vals]):-
  getcardvalue(Card,Val),
  getcardvalueList(Cards,Vals).
```

No need for append, the list constructions is done by means of patterns in head'arguments.
Note that you should avoid to redefine library predicates, like [append](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3)/3.

Comment: yes, Thanks.
I did not need to use append.
i was using getcardvalue() to get a value associated with a card.
once I implemented that I just needed to call the same function where ever I needed to compare or look at the value. That did the trick